# How to add a DataTemplate to CollectionContainer?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Here is my specific scenario.

The Window resources code:

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AdditionalStringData" Source="{Binding ViewModelObservableCollection_String}"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AdditionalCustomObjectData" Source="{Binding ViewModelObservableCollection_CustomObject}"/>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
...
```

The part where I need to display the Collection:

```
...
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelTextProperty}"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding ViewModelRelayCommand}">Command</Button>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource AdditionalStringData}}" />
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource AdditionalCustomObjectData}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
...
```

The ViewModel (assume that it is binded correctly)

```
...
private string ViewModelTextProperty  { get; set; } = "Sample Text";
public RelayCommand ViewModelRelayCommand { ... }
private ObservableCollection<string> ViewModelObservableCollection_String { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
private ObservableCollection<CustomObject> ViewModelObservableCollection_CustomObject { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();
...
```

The Class CutomObject (it may not be needed to show):

```
...
public class CustomObject
{
    public string firstString;
    public string secondString;

    public CustomObject()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Assume that the `ObservableCollection`s has proper contents.

My question is: How can I display the collection properly?
Here is the criteria:

- On the first line, there will be a TextBlock with a Text inside it that says "Sample Text"
- Next is a button with a label "Command"
- Next lines (as many as `ViewModelObservableCollection_String` items) are TextBlocks. Its text should be the value of the individual item of `ViewModelObservableCollection_String`.
- Next lines (as many as `ViewModelObservableCollection_CustomObject` items) are TextBoxes. Its text should be the value of the individual item of `ViewModelObservableCollection_CustomObject` (concatenation of `firstString` and `secondString`).

As you can see, the content of the StackPanel is a merge of more than one Collection with different `DataTemplate`.

Please ask for clarification if something is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `DataTrigger` inside `ItemTemplate` to change `ControlTemplate` of `Control` used, while comparing `Type`. For this use a converter which would return the type.

   or,
2. Use `ContentControl` as `ItemTemplate`.
3. Define `DataTemplate` specifying `DataType` in it. `ContentControl` will automatically pick appropriate `DataTemplate` for its `ContentTemplate`.

**Second Approach (Recommended)**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        ...
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <TextBlock Background="ForestGreen" Text="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomObject}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{Binding firstString}"/>
                <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{Binding secondString}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<ItemsControl>
... 
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate it more? I am relatively new with WPF.

Comment: I think, your second suggestion is easier. Can you please provide an example code? If not, please give me some reference about it.